# python sorting a list of tuple of int,str

Tags: python

Given a list of tuple of int, str, I need to find a way to sort this from highest to lowest, without using sorted. 
So if I have:

```
list = [(1, 'orange'), (3, 'banana'), (2, 'pear'), (1, 'apple')]
```

I should have returned this sorted by number, and if numbers are same, by alphabetical order such as:

```
['banana', 'pear', 'apple', 'orange']
```

is there a way to do this without using the sorted function and using arguments in sort method? I am a beginner in python and I have no idea how to even approach this problem, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `is there a way to do this without using the sorted function and using arguments in sort method?` Are you talking about `sorted()` and `list.sort()`? You do realise these are pretty much the exact same things

Comment: I am **NOT** going to answer until you clarify why you should not use `sorted` and `sort` :)

Answer (score 1):

Not using `sorted()` means that we have to use one more line, but here is how you could do it:

```
>>> your_tuples = [(1, 'orange'), (3, 'banana'), (2, 'pear'), (1, 'apple')]
>>> your_tuples.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))
>>> [t[1] for t in your_tuples]
['banana', 'pear', 'apple', 'orange']
```